# How to use plsql loops without installing oracle

Tags: database, oracle, sqlite, plsql

Hello I have a database file (.sqlite) now I want to use `plsql` for performing operation like looping, if condition with sql query.

How it is possible ? I don't want to install the oracle software.

Comment: So you are asking "how can I use Oracle without installing Oracle"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no clear. I am asking that Can we execute plsql loops/procedures as like you can execute sql queries in SQLite Database Browser without installing oracle or any database software

Comment: PL/SQL is an oracle proprietary extended language. it won't run anywhere other than in an Oracle Database. I think what your question SHOULD BE is 'does SQLite support conditional logic and looping?'

Comment: You realise that SQLite and Oracle are completely unrelated other than they are both databases, right?

Comment: @thatJeffSMith You should definitively post that as an answer

Comment: SQLite does not support PL/SQL. PL/SQL is only supported (to the best of my knowledge) by Oracle and IBM's DB2 product. PostgreSQL supports pgplsql, which is similar-but-not-identical. As far as I'm aware SQLite does not have a procedural extension language. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) -- *the Structured Query Langage* -- is the "standard" language to query relational databases. Most, if not all, RDBMS vendors endorse SQL, or to be precise their *own version* of SQL. Even if it is normalized by ANSI since the 80s, 100% compliance is rarely achieved. And many RDBMS accepts vendor-specific extensions to SQL.

In other words,  Oracle's implementation of SQL and SQLite's one are not identical. But the core language is the same. That why you can often/sometimes write the same queries for both products.

---

[PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) in other hand is Oracle *proprietary* Procedural Language. It was designated in the 90s *by Oracle Corporation* for their *own* database.  Few other products support PL/SQL either because they are owned by Oracle Corporation ([TimesTen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TimesTen)) or, I suppose, as a competitive feature ([IBM DB2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2)).

Instead of adhering to Oracle's *proprietary* language, some other RDBMS complies to [SQL/PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM). It's a procedural language designated as an extension to SQL and normalized by ISO. Despite resemblance to PL/SQL, it's a different language. MySQL and PostgreSQL have support for SQL/PSM at various levels.

As far as I know, SQLite does not support SQL/PSM, nor PL/SQL. The main reason is probably that SQLite is designated to be an *embedded* database. As the host language already supports *loop*, *conditional structures* and any other construct you might require, there is no need to support a specific procedural language at DB level. And given the large variety of [languages supporting SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#Programming_languages), you should probably be able to find one that suits your needs/taste.

---

However, if you really need to use PL/SQL with SQLite, your last option is probably to use (write?) a PL/SQL compiler that will translate from PL/SQL to some other high-level language compatible with SQLite (C, C++, Java, ...). [Metatranz's StepSqlite](http://www.metatranz.com/stepsqlite/FAQ.html) is such a product. It's a proprietary product. And I never used it. So I can't tell at which extend PL/SQL is really supported nor if it is or not production ready. That being said, as of myself I wouldn't push toward that direction,  unless you have very very specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an *embedded* database; it is designed to be used from inside some programming language.
You can do operations like looping or if conditions in that language.

There is no separate database server, so there is no need to ship code to the server to avoid client/server communication overhead.

Comment: Yes right but you can execute sql queries in SQLite Database Browser without installing oracle or any database software if you have sqlite file & i am looking for same like for plsql

Comment: @williams: no such capability exists. Take Jimmy Buffett's advice: "Breathe in, breathe out, move on".